# is it possible to compare tests results from two non-consecutive jobs in jenkins?

Tags: junit, jenkins

I want to compare the tests results of two jobs in jenkins. in my case these jobs are not consecutive so the usual tests resutls view of the job is not good enough.
Is there any way to get this view? or is it possible write such plugin myself?

Comment: Have you tried to search for a plugin that already exists?

Comment: yes. do you know any? I haven't found one.

Comment: With the brief description that you put out here, I see only two options. 1. write your own plugin. 2. create a third job that collects the test results of your two jobs and creates the necessary metrics.

Comment: Can you please clarify the question: what exactly do you mean by comparing the tests? Is a page containing links to both test results pages is enough, or you would like to actually incorporate the tests together as if they ran from the same job (and thus could be displayed together on the same graph, etc.)?

Comment: for exmaple: a table that foreach test will say here it fail and here it pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar, although not exactly the same setup. In your circumstances what I do would work like this: job A stores its test results (say, junit xml's) keyed by its build id and kicks off job C via the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) passing to it the location of the test results. Job C then can either simply publish those tests or do some additional processing on them. Job  B does the same thing as job A as far as its tests and kicking off of job C are concerned. Then all of your results are aggregated in job C.

The additional processing that job C does may include storing the results of test A in a temporary location and then processing them later together with the results of job B. This is not automatic, but still much easier than writing a whole new plugin. Also you can customize it in any way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it visually using [Test Results Analyzer Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Test+Results+Analyzer+Plugin). Under 'Test Results Analyzer' > Options you can select more than the last 10 builds or all builds. You can expand Traffic-light Red Green Yellow table for each test result so can see trends in test history as well as checking results on individual jobs.